# Compiling .Net Framework Project at command prompt give CS0006 while there is not error in Visual Studio, why?

Tags: c#, .net, build, compilation

Compiling .Net Framework Project at command prompt give CS0006 while there is not error in Visual Studio, why?

I tried to compile with:

- dotnet build
- devenv /build

Trying to commpile either the solution or the final .csproj.

Using or not using a "dotnet restore" before compiling.

It always game me error "CS0006" in all cases.

Error: (thanks to: TheGeneral to add that information in comments)

CS0006 : Metadata file 'dll_name' could not be found. The program was compiled and
explicitly passed the name of a file that contained metadata; however, the .dll was not found.

Comment: For those who have no idea what this error is "*Metadata file 'dll_name' could not be found. The program was compiled and explicitly passed the name of a file that contained metadata; however, the .dll was not found. For more information*" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0006

Answer (score 0):

After many hours and many trial and error, I finally find a way:

```
dotnet restore --force-evaluate
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv" /build Debug Solution.sln
```

Please let met know if it works for you ;-) !!!